# Retrieve last message of all the users that match the name of the use entered

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to retrieve the last message sent or received that matches the name of the user entered in the text box through AJAX, But I have not been able to write a proper MySQL query.

Here is my code:

```
    $name=$_GET['name']; 
    $query_get_user_id = "SELECT id from login WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['login_user']."'"; 
    $result_get_userid=$mysqli->query($query_get_user_id);
    $user_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_get_userid);
    $user_id=$user_row['id'];

    $query_second_user_id = "SELECT id from login WHERE name LIKE '".$name."%'"; 
    $result_second_get_userid=$mysqli->query($query_second_user_id);
    $user_second_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_second_get_userid);
    $second_user_id=$user_second_row['id'];

    $query_get_all_users ="SELECT DISTINCT sender_id,receiver_id from message WHERE ((sender_id='".$user_id."' AND receiver_id='".$second_user_id."') OR (sender_id='".$user_id."' AND receiver_id='".$second_user_id."')) order by timestamp desc";

   $result_get_all_users=$mysqli->query($query_get_all_users);
   while($retrieve_user_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_get_all_users)){
```

Here is my table structure:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables to rank each user’s message according to its timestamp, ranking the most recent message as 1 and only keeping messages with rank 1.

```
select * from (
    select m.*,
      @rn := if(u.id = @prevUserId, @rn+1, 1) rn,
      @prevUserId := u.id
    from users u 
    join messages m on u.id in (m.sender_id,m.receiver_id)
    where u.name like 'name%'
    order by u.id, timestamp desc
) t1 where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Fuzzy for your answer but this query is not working. It is showing error message -Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Sorry Fuzzy but this query is not giving desired result i have added image of what result i want please see to it and help me to solve my problem.

Comment: I only want unique name rows that matched the name passed, in descending order of timestamp but above query returns many rows.

Comment: @user3653474 see update - just remove the first `%` if you want to match names that begin with the passed query

Answer (score 0):

sorry i get that wrong, I developed query for only logged in user or one user, Now I get your point.

Please give a try to this updated query. I tested it on local DB and was working as expected.

---

```
    SELECT *
FROM message mm
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT sender, MAX(createdtime) AS MaxDateTime
    FROM message
    WHERE sender IN 
    (select id from user where name like 'search_filter%')
    GROUP BY sender) groupedmm
ON mm.sender = groupedmm.sender 
AND mm.createdtime = groupedmm.MaxDateTime;
```